# PHP Array reference, modifying array values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to modify an array when looping through it and increment certain values.

```
     $data = ['traits' => [[['amt' => 1]]]];
     var_dump($data['traits']);

      foreach ($data['traits'] as $key => &$index) {

        foreach ($index as $key => &$value) {

          $value['amt'] = $value['amt']++; // This should increment

          if (in_array($key, $input)) {
            $i++;
            $insert["field_".$i] = $key."_1";
          }
        }
      }

      var_dump($data['traits']);    // SAME AS PREVIOUS VAR_DUMP
```

Comment: Provide your array structure or sample array

Comment: Replace $key in the inner loop by another variable. In your case it gets overwritten and is not what you intended. And do you really want to set $insert in the if clause? Please explain what you are achieving to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in the loop is undefined:

```
$value['amt'] = $value['amt']++;
```

The outcome of that depends on what's evaluated first. In this case `$value['amt']++` seems to be evaluated first and then assigned to `$value['amt']` again; the side effect of the increment is lost.

On the other hand, the following statement will work as expected:

```
$value['amt']++;
```